# NullPointerException using getResource

Tags: java, opencv, getresource

I'm trying to create some application to recognize faces, following [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html). However, whenever I run the code below, I get this error: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
class DetectFaceDemo {
    public void run () {
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = 
            new CascadeClassifier(getClass()
                  .getResource("/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml").getPath());
    }
}
```

Am I supposed to copy the xml file to some directory?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done this part of the tutorial? `Next, copy lbpcascade_frontalface.xml from opencv/data/ into the resources directory`

Comment: Yes! It's in "C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LenaFaceDetection\build\classes\main\resources" directory. Is it the right one?

Comment: I believe it should be located in `C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LenaFaceDetection\build\classes\src\mai‌​n\resources`. I'm not sure if it should be in the `build` or `classes` directory though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, I think you put your `main/resources` in the wrong directory (and you forgot the `src` part of the tree).

From the tutorial, you should have the following structure:
`src/main/java/<Java packages or classes>`

You already have the `src` folder there. Create a `main` directory in `src`, and a `resources` directory in `main`. Put your XML file in the `resources` directory and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've put in `C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LenaFaceDetection\src\lenafacedetection` and (don't know why) it worked!

Comment: @AdrianoValente: no, don't put in the entire path, since if you do that, and then try to use the resource in a jar, your fried. Try Stefan's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in the code to find the classpath and copy the `xml` and `png` files to this location.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```